# Insert data from another table based on condition, if not insert specific value PSQL

Tags: sql, psql

I have table A with an id column and a bunch of others. I also have table B which has an id column like table A and also another column called countries. However, not all id in table A are in table B. I want to insert a new column into table A called countries2 that basically inserts the countries from table B that corresponds to the ids in both tables. If a specific id from A does not exist in B, then it always puts in the VARCHAR 'none' into countries2. 
So for example if Table A has the ids 1, 2, 3, 4 and table B looks like:
id--country
1---'foo1'
3---'foo2'

I want table A to become something like:
id--country2--other original data from table A
1---'foo1'--...
2---'none'--...
3---'foo2'--...
4---'none'--...

Comment: Your question is quite confusing... Damn !

Comment: It's not a confusing question, but the answer may not be extremely straight-forward...

You want this done entirely in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first alter your TableA to add an extra column (i.e yourNewColumn) of type varchar/varchar2

to add the column try something like

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD COLUMN yourNewColumn varchar(10);
```

Then you can use something like below to update TableA

```
UPDATE TableA
SET yourNewColumn = ISNULL(TableB.countries, 'none')
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
```

The ISNULL function in PostgreSQL might be something like

```
SET yourNewColumn = CASE WHEN TableB.countries IS NULL THEN 'none' ELSE TableB.countries END
```